# get plotBand on Highcharts to span first column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to get a column chart done. Basically, it displays readings of some data over the year, the categories are months. So, I need to colorize the background of a month whenever certain requirements are met. The thing is, I can't get plotBands to cover January.

```
plotBands: [{
  from: 0,
  to: 0.5
}]
```

This will colorize the column from the middle of January to its end. What I want is to get Highcharts to colorize it from the start of January to its end. Any thoughts? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, never mind. It seems like 'from: -0.5' works just fine. I couldn't get it work the first time, but I think it was just some other random mistake. Thanks anyways, guys. Gonna let this question here, so other people can be helped. xoxo